# Shared printer as local printer in Windows

Tags: windows-7, network-shares, network-printer

I want to use a shared printer as local printer (because I have to find them with local service user that has visibility only to local printers) in a Windows 7 environment.

Is there a solution to set it as local?

Please consider that I'm speaking of a shared printer (printer connected to another computer) and not a network printer, therefore I cannot use a TCP/IP port to a specific IP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this. Follow the same procedure to add a local printer and instead of adding a "TCP/IP Port" add a "Local Port" and for the Name of the port specify the UNC path to the shared printer as: `\\<IP or Hostname>\PrnSharedName`

It's been a while since I did this, but I remember having some permission issues with machines. If these machines are on a domain, you'll probably be OK as long as the printer has been shared with `everyone` permissions.

If these machines are not on a domain, you may need to adjust some local security policies that allows anonymous connections, and to treat anonymous as everyone. Totally a security risk, but may be necessary in strange environments that required you to ask this question in the first place. :)

I believe the connection is made from the SYSTEM account, and not a logged on user. So the computer account needs access to the printer.

Comment: I could create the port as you suggested, but an application running as service with user "local service" cannot print, it finds the printerm but cannot print. Maybe it happens because of security policy, I tried to add print capabilities to "Everyon" on host computer, but nothing changes.

Comment: Did you do a test print from Windows? Just tackle one problem at a time. Without further details about your network environment, if it is a domain or workgroup, or anything you have done to address security permissions I'm not able to point you in the right direction. You should update your question to provide more details about your network.

Comment: I cannot (or I don't know how) send a test print with localservice user. However, you answered my first question so I'm accepting it

Comment: No, I'm suggesting sending a test print from Windows 'devices and printers'. Know that the printer works first, then tackle your service.

Comment: Oh yes, I tried it with a standard user. Seems that localservice cannot print